# How can I launch chenrocks/uniter with NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3090 GPU?

Tags: docker, pytorch, nvidia

```bash
docker run --gpus '"'device=$CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'"' --ipc=host --rm -it \
    --mount src=$(pwd),dst=/src,type=bind \
    --mount src=$OUTPUT,dst=/storage,type=bind \
    --mount src=$PRETRAIN_DIR,dst=/pretrain,type=bind,readonly \
    --mount src=$TXT_DB,dst=/txt,type=bind,readonly \
    --mount src=$IMG_DIR,dst=/img,type=bind,readonly \
    -e NVIDIA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=$CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES \
    -w /src chenrocks/uniter
```

When I run this file, it prints error

```
NVIDIA Release 19.05 (build 6411784) PyTorch Version 1.1.0a0+828a6a3
```

...

```
WARNING: Detected NVIDIA NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3090 GPU, which is not yet supported in this version of the container
ERROR: No supported GPU(s) detected to run this container
```

it doesn't fit with my NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3090 GPU
so I want to change version to 22.05
but when I run this,

```bash
docker run --gpus '"'device=$CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'"' --ipc=host --rm
-it nvcr.io/nvidia/pytorch:22.05-py3 \
    --mount src=$(pwd),dst=/src,type=bind \
    --mount src=$OUTPUT,dst=/storage,type=bind \
    --mount src=$PRETRAIN_DIR,dst=/pretrain,type=bind,readonly \
    --mount src=$TXT_DB,dst=/txt,type=bind,readonly \
    --mount src=$IMG_DIR,dst=/img,type=bind,readonly \
    -e NVIDIA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=$CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES \
    -w /src chenrocks/uniter
```

it prints error

```
/opt/nvidia/nvidia_entrypoint.sh: line 49: exec: --: invalid option
exec: usage: exec [-cl] [-a name] [command [arguments ...]] [redirection ...]
```

I'd really appreciate it if you could tell me how to change the version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second `docker run` command specifies 2 images:

```
docker run ... nvcr.io/nvidia/pytorch:22.05-py3 chenrocks/uniter
```

You can only pass one.

---

Also note the general format of the [`docker run`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/) command:

```
$ docker run [OPTIONS] IMAGE [COMMAND] [ARG...]
```

---

**UPDATE**

> But if the docker image's nvidia/pytorch version doesn't fit my GPU, can I not use that docker image? Or is there something I can do?

You could try editing the [`Dockerfile`](https://github.com/ChenRocks/UNITER/blob/master/Dockerfile) of the referenced project to build a custom docker image.

Something like this:

```bash
git clone https://github.com/ChenRocks/UNITER.git
cd UNITER
# replace the first line of the Dockerfile with:
# FROM nvcr.io/nvidia/pytorch:22.05-py3
docker build .
# ...
# Successfully built <image_id>
```

Then simply edit your `docker run` command to use your custom built image:

```
docker run ... <image_id>
```

It looks like that at least one other person had a [similar issue](https://github.com/ChenRocks/UNITER/issues/90). Unfortunately the project is not actively maintained so it's difficult to get any kind of support when trying to make it work with the latest hardware.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answer. I think I should use chenrocks/uniter. But if the docker image's nvidia/pytorch version doesn't fit my GPU, can I not use that docker image? Or is there something I can do?

Comment: @유은석 Were you able to build your custom image and start up the container?